# Python 3.5.2 print function not working

Tags: python

I am using python version 3.5.2 and the print function isn't working for me. THis is the code. I recieve an error saying: "missing preantheses in calling to print"

```
print 'Output After Training:'
```

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Add the parenthesis:

```
print('Output After Training:')
```

If you need compatibility for code so works with Python 2 or 3, use:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the start of the code file and then use Python 3 way of using `print()`.

Learn more about `print()` in Python 3 at:

- https://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php

Comment: thanks, how could I have missed that :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is in the error... `missing parentheses in calling to print`

Python3 requires you to use parentheses when using `print` - i.e. `print("text")`